# Memory leak issue caused by each loop

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have a question regarding to Memory Leak and functions $.getJSON and $.each loop.
I'm taking data from external JSON file that will be periodically updating. I use 2 functions to iterate data from JSON file and another to display it on the page using 5 Unordered lists.
Also I use function for pause these iteration. The problem is that this script taking too much memory and CPU resources. From my understanding the function .remove() doesn't delete object from memory but only remoes it from DOM Structure. How can I clean memory after outputing 5 UL on the page and prevent memory leaking? Also, my function for pause stops the animation but doesn't stop the .each loop for some reason which also causing problems with memory consumption Is there any way to make pause for .Each loop?
This is my script:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="Viacheslav" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>JSON TEST-1</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content_div">
        <ul></ul>  
  </div>
<input type=button value="pause/play" onclick="continue_reporting = ( continue_reporting == 1 ) ? 0 : 1;">
    <script type="text/javascript">        

        var counter = 0;
        var delay_entry = 0;
        delay_fetch = 0;
        var continue_reporting = 1;      
        var node_list = new Array( );
        //var content_div = $("#content_div");
        var child = 0;


        fetch_data(); // initial run
        function fetch_data()
        {

          $.getJSON('js/list.json?i=' + Math.random(), function(data){
              //console.log("data.length: " + data.length );
              $.each(data, function(key,value){
                counter++
                setTimeout( pusher, 1000 * delay_entry, value );
                delay_entry++;                

              })



          })  
          setTimeout( fetch_data, 1000 * delay_fetch );
          delay_fetch++;

        }

        function pusher( value )
        {      

            if ( continue_reporting == 1 ) 
            {
              $("#content_div").append("<ul>" + 
                                    "<li>" +  value.reg + "</li>" +
                                    "<li>" +  value.bids[0].ind + "</li>" +
                                    "<li>" +  value.bids[0].v + "</li>" +
                                "</ul>");
                child++;             

               if (child > 4){
              $("#content_div ul:first-child").remove();              
              }

              }
              console.log("children = " + child);

        }


    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **1.** Clean up your sample code, it's a formatting mess and even has unused variables (`node_list`? what's this?) **2.** How about some sample data from the json service? You've only really provided half the equation. **3.** Your pause buttons changes the `continue_reporting` variable but neither `fetch_data()` nor its `$.each` loop checks the variable, so of course the button won't pause it. **4.** Is it really your intention to query the server every second then slowly increase the delay? A 1 second delay is pretty heavy-handed (it should be more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to delete objects in JavaScript; it is a *garbage collected* language. Having said that, you can make things easier for the garbage collector when it does run by NULL-ing any references you have when removing something (this is especially important in older IE versions which give up if there are too many reference loops in garbage memory). This doesn't apply so much to the DOM structure, which is well managed (no loops), but to your variables. The garbage collector will run whenever the browser thinks too much memory is being used.

You cannot pause a JavaScript timeout, but you can cancel it and start it again later. For example, you could create an array;

```
var timers = [];
```

then fill it:

```
var tm = +new Date( );
(then in .each loop)
timers.push( {'ref': setTimeout( pusher, 1000 * delay_entry, value ), 'when': tm + 1000 * delay_entry, 'with': value} );
```

now you can cancel them:

```
var tm = +new Date( );
for( var i = 0; i < timers.length; ++ i ) {
    clearTimeout( timers[i].ref );
    timers[i].ref = undefined;
    timers[i].when -= tm;
}
```

and re-start them:

```
var tm = +new Date( );
for( var i = 0; i < timers.length; ++ i ) {
    if( timers[i].when > 0 ) {
        timers[i].ref = setTimeout( pusher, timers[i].when, timers[i].with );
    }
    timers[i].when += tm;
}
```

Don't forget to clear the array out as you process it with timers.shift()

Back to the memory, you have a few issues. First, you'd be better off having a global value storing the updates to apply which you push values into and shift out, so that you don't have lots of references flying around. Secondly you ought to change your timeouts into a single interval (setInterval) which renders the code above moot (!). This especially applies to calling fetch_data, because at the moment you have recursion which means lots of memory is never being freed. And you should fix delay_fetch to start at 1 (currently it runs twice in quick succession when it first loads. In fact I think you have a few issues with your delays that you need to think about). Try this form, which requests every 5 seconds without increasing timeout and implements the changes one at a time in second intervals after downloading, instead of getting perpetually longer and longer waits:

```
var delay_fetch = 5;
var node_list = [];
var child = 0;

function process_data(data){
    var delay_entry = 0;
    $.each(data, function(key,value){
        setTimeout( pusher, 1000 * delay_entry, value );
        delay_entry++;                
    })
}
function fetch_data(){
    $.getJSON('js/list.json?i=' + Math.random(), process_data);
}
setInterval( fetch_data, 1000 * delay_fetch );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try these solutuons

Answer (score 0):

Keep the cleanup as a mirror image of the newly added content:

```
          $("#content_div").html(null);              
          // may add .remove() too to be safe.
```

Then completely redraw the list if needed.

```
          $("#content_div").html( yourNewContent );
```

Rules of thumb:

1. If you add something, completely remove it from the dom before adding something new. I wouldn't trust append.
2. jQuery plugins can leak memory like a faucet.  You may need to disable all plugins first before running a test.  IE 8 can be particular bad with managing memory, so for the best test, use the worst browser.  :)
3. test with a static copy of the JSON.  I could see jQuery being a bit leaky here (particularly with jsonp) so you may want to roll your own ajax methods.  Set all the callbacks/properties/objects to null when finished with them.   Javascript is prone to circular reference leaks.